# Почему True != False => False

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor

Написал простой код с функцией исключающего или, которая возвращает значение bool.

```
def xor(x, y):
    return x != y


if xor(bool(input()), bool(input())):
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
```

При этом значение функции всегда False

Но например 1 != 0, должно выйти True

Почему так происходит и чего я не понимаю?

Comment: потому что input возвращает строку. а bool строки всегда True.

Comment: @strawdog кроме пустой строки

Comment: @strawdog, я так понимаю самым не затратным способом будет организовать ввод вот так `bool(int(input()))`? Если что вот так все работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите работать с числами, то конвертируйте значения `input()` в числа:

```py
def xor(x, y):
    return x != y


if xor(bool(int(input())), bool(int(input()))):
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
```

Преобразование непустой строки к `bool` всегда даёт `True`. А вот преобразование к `bool` числа выдаст `False`, если будет передан `0`.

Если же Вы хотите подавать на вход для сравнения чистые строки, уберите преобразование к `bool`.